# Google+: Get the friendlist of users in offline mode

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I want to find the list of friends of Google+ user who have authorized the app without asking for authorization again.

For example: Once the user login using the Google+ to my website, I store the auth token, code, Google+ user id in the db.
So once that is done I want to find the list of users friends in his circle. 
I managed to get the first part working and it saves the auth token, code, Google+ user id in the db.
But in the second case i.e. finding the list of users friends, I again get a the screen where user have to authorize the app.

Can someone please help me in this?

Also **is it possible to get all the user details in offline mode like using the auth token, code, Google+ user id which is in the db?**

Initial code(login):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/Google_Client.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

$this->sn_obj = new Google_Client($google_app_id, $google_secret_key,  $call_back_url);
$this->plus_obj = new Google_PlusService($this->sn_obj);

$this->sn_obj->setRedirectUri($call_back_url);
$this->sn_obj->setState($redirect_url);
$requestVisibleActions = array('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity','http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity');
$this->sn_obj->setRequestVisibleActions($requestVisibleActions);
$this->sn_obj->setAccessType('offline');

$this->sn_obj->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));
$this->sn_obj->createAuthUrl();
```

In callback page:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/Google_Client.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

$this->sn_obj = new Google_Client($google_app_id, $google_secret_key,  $call_back_url);
$this->plus_obj = new Google_PlusService($this->sn_obj);

$this->sn_obj->setRedirectUri($call_back_url);
$this->sn_obj->setState($redirect_url);
$requestVisibleActions = array('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity','http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity');
$this->sn_obj->setRequestVisibleActions($requestVisibleActions);
$this->sn_obj->setAccessType('offline');

$this->sn_obj->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));

$this->sn_obj->authenticate();
$google_auth_token = $this->sn_obj->getAccessToken();
$google_user_info =  $this->plus_obj->people->get('me');
```

Friends listing page:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/Google_Client.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

$this->sn_obj = new Google_Client($google_app_id, $google_secret_key,  $call_back_url);
$this->plus_obj = new Google_PlusService($this->sn_obj);
$this->sn_obj->setRedirectUri($call_back_uri);
$this->sn_obj->authenticate();
$user_info = $this->plus_obj->people->listPeople($token['oauth_uid'],'visible');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get get it done

On Friends listing page:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/Google_Client.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/social-api/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

$this->sn_obj = new Google_Client($google_app_id, $google_secret_key,  $call_back_url);
$this->plus_obj = new Google_PlusService($this->sn_obj);
if(!$this->sn_obj->getAccessToken()){
    $this->sn_obj->refreshToken($refresh_token_from_db);
}
$google_auth_token = $this->sn_obj->getAccessToken();
$google_auth_token_arr = json_decode($google_auth_token,true);

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'.$uid_from_db.'/people/visible?access_token='.$google_auth_token_arr['access_token'].'&format=json';

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$user_info = json_decode($contents, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when working in offline mode, you need to store the entire object that comes back from the server - not just the auth token. This object includes the long-lived refresh token as well as information about when it needs to do a refresh. Passing this entire token to the service allows it to refresh the token for you.

The answer you came up with looks like you do the refresh yourself manually - which is fine, but shouldn't be necessary in general.

In some cases, if a user authorizes your app before you have requested offline mode, and you later request offline mode, you *still* won't get the refresh token. Google will only give a refresh token when asked if there is no auth token, current or expired, that was issued. There are two ways around this:

1. When you switch to using offline mode, invalidate your old client id / secret and start using a new one. *or*
2. Have the user de-authorize your app via https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens or (if you're using Google+ Sign-In) via https://plus.google.com/apps

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your last point. could you please elaborate?